# How to create .NET client classes for access to PTV Developer?

Tags: ptv-developer

I am trying to connect to PTV Developer based on the OPEN API specification. The goal is to develop a winform application on the desktop.

https://api.myptv.com/meta/services/routing/v1/openapi.json
https://api.myptv.com/meta/services/geocoding/v1/openapi.json
and so on.

I tried several approaches such as Visual Studio's **add REST api client** but failed. Looks like the implementation of the OPEN API generators shows "room for improvement", e.g. I encounter issues with collections in the signatures:
Routing:

```
results.Add(Results.POLYLINE);
results.Add(Results.TOLL_EVENTS);
results.Add(Results.MANEUVER_EVENTS);
RouteResponse routeResponse = svcRouting.CalculateRouteAsync(
  allLines, null, "EUR_TRAILER_TRUCK",
  null, null, results).Result;
```

The last parameter of the method is supposed to be a IEnumerable.
Works fine if results contains a single element but fails if 2 or more elements are added.

Can you give me some guidance? Some recommended or approved client generators?

Thanks in advance,

Bernd

PS : I know that the target of PTV Developer is web based applications but my client wants to implement a desktop winform ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The **Add->REST API Client...** which seems to be preinstalled with Visual Studio uses the **NSWAG** generator, which isn't fully compatible with the PTV developer API specification.

PTV Developer is verified for compatibility with [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). If you want to generate your clients directly in Visual Studio, you need a VS extension that supports OpenAPI Generator, for example [REST API Client Code Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChristianResmaHelle.ApiClientCodeGenerator).

I have tested this successfully for a WinForms project with .NET Framework 4.7.2:

- In Visual Studio open **Tools->Extensions->Manage Extensions**
- Search for **"REST API Client Code Generator"**
- Important: After installation open **Tools->Options**
- Then select **REST API Client Code Generator->OpenAPI Generator->Emit Default Value** and set it to **False**
- To import an API, right-click on **Solution Explorer->Add->New REST API Client->Generate with OpenAPI**
- Enter the Url and a file name.

The generator creates also synchronous methods, which would be better suitable for WinForms applications. You can find detailed information about the depencies on the website of the plugin.