# assemblage of IEmunerable<string> causes invalid web request

Tags: ptv-developer

I am currently evaluating the Geocoding API (and further APIs in the PTV Developer API collection) through C# / Visual Studio 2019. The client classes have been generated via OPEN API and I can successfully gather a SearchPlacesByTextAsync request with the mandatory parameters. But when I try to use some optional parameters such as the categoryFilter (EInumerable) I am running into errors. I am using a List object to build the parameter. Any clue why this crashes?
How can I add one or more categories into this?
The error seems to occur in the source code that is generated in the OPEN API toolchain.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                button1.Update();
                //
                List<string> country = new List<string>();
                if (tbxCountry.Text != "")
                    country.AddRange(tbxCountry.Text.Split(','));
                List<string> category = new List<string>();
                if (tbxCategoryFilter.Text != "")
                    category.AddRange(tbxCategoryFilter.Text.Split(','));

                string language = (tbxLanguage.Text != "") ? tbxLanguage.Text : null;
                PlacesSearchResult result = svcGeocoding.SearchPlacesByTextAsync(tbxText.Text, category, country, language).Result;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = result.Places
                    .OrderBy(o => o.Name)
                    .Select((p, i) => new
                    {
                        i,
                        p.Name,
                        p.Address.CountryName,
                        p.Address.State,
                        p.Address.Province,
                        p.Address.PostalCode,
                        p.Address.City,
                        p.Address.District,
                        p.Address.Subdistrict,
                        p.Address.Street,
                        p.Address.HouseNumber,
                        p.FormattedAddress,
                        CategoryIds = (p.CategoryIds != null) ? String.Join(",",p.CategoryIds) : null,
                        p.Quality.TotalScore,
                        ref_Longitude = p.ReferencePosition.Longitude.ToString(coord_tostring),
                        ref_Latitude = p.ReferencePosition.Latitude.ToString(coord_tostring),
                        road_Longitude = p.RoadAccessPosition.Longitude.ToString(coord_tostring),
                        road_Latitude = p.RoadAccessPosition.Latitude.ToString(coord_tostring)
                    }).ToArray();
                //
                button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
                button1.Update();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                button1.Update();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the wrong generator. Read here for an instruction [how-to-create-net-client-classes-for-access-to-ptv-developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71355601/17573130)

Then the code will work as expected:

```cs
var placesApi = new Geocoding.Api.PlacesApi(new Geocoding.Client.Configuration {
    ApiKey = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        ["apiKey"] = "<your api key>"
    }
});

var places = placesApi.SearchPlacesByText("Taxi Karlsruhe", 
    categoryFilter: new List<string>{ "navteq-lcms:400-4100-0041", "navteq-lcms:700-7200-0256" },
    countryFilter: new List<string>{ "NL", "DE", "BE" });
```